# How To Show A Entry In A List Of Either Titles Or Text

Tags: lists, title, ease-of-use

In our Ms Access CRM program, we can make notes on a customer. I am creating a way to have "quick" cards, that the user can choose rather than type. A Quick Card can have either a text or a title and text. If a title is provided, the list will show that title, otherwise it will show the text.

[image: List Of Cards]

If I open the selected Quick Card, the following will show:

[image: Please Change - Butt Title Text]

Some of these cards don't have titles though, like the "This Is A Test" quick card.

Is there a user friendly way to let the user know if it is a title or not?

EDIT:

Decided to use a Title (text) method. The solution isn't great, but it works.

[image: Finished Product]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm since you are displaying two different fields in a single field based on internal logic, the interface is very confusing.

Ideal situation is to have two different fields, or else if you insist on combining then do this.

```
 Untitled      - this some body text ...
 Awesome title - (blank)
 ok title      - better body
```

This doesn't lead to any confusion or require the user to understand your logic and make another mental note of it.

You can substitute any convention that your users will understand, instead of Untitled and (blank). Maybe use different fonts to indicate the difference?

Comment: I went a similar route. Title (Text). I put the change in my question. Thanks for the ideas.